# post data into database without template in django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views, django-3.0

I want to post data into database without using templates in django.

Here is my model class:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
   eno = models.IntegerField()
   ename = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   esal = models.FloatField()
   eadd = models.TextField(max_length=40)  

def emp(request):

   eno = request.POST[1289],
   ename = request.POST['siddarth'],
   esal = request.POST[20190.24],
   eadd = request.POST['india'],
   save_data = Employee.objects.create(eno=eno,ename=ename,esal=esal,eadd=eadd)
   save_data.save()
   return JsonResponse(save_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution does not answer the question properly. You just need to make a request, it doesn't matter from where it is coming.

**1. Use Postman:** You can make a request to server with the postman ( or any other API testing application).

**2. Use CURL:** You can use CURL command to make a request to your server.
For eg:

```
curl -X POST -H -d "{\"eno\": \"120\", \"ename\": \"roy\", \"esal\": \"3212\", \"eadd\": \"England\"}" http://some_url
```

**3. Use terminal commands:** You can directly add a record to your database by going to the terminal and running the command `python manage.py shell`. After that you need to import your model in the shell.

```sh
>>> from your_app.models import Employee
>>> Employee.objects.create(eno=120,ename='roy',esal=3212,eadd='England')
```

Comment: i know whatever points you answered. but i question is how to save data into database using only through views.

Comment: please refer previous question i was mentioned clearly. post data into database use views only .

Comment: ok..then, if you don't mind can you give the sample solution for views.